# Binary plist Vs normal plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa

What are the advantages of sending binary plist over network than simple plist. Also, how fast binary plists are to process on client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're usually significantly smaller, and a bit faster to process, than plists in the XML format; unless you're dealing with a lot of data, the difference in processing time will be negligible.